# Cannot get my functions to see my dictionary

Tags: c#, function, visual-studio-2012, dictionary

I have declared a dictionary right at the start of my program as such

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }
```

and I have a function that fills the dictionary using a string it is sent

```
    public IDictionary<string, int> SortTextIntoDictionary(string text)
    {
        text = text.Replace(",", ""); //Just cleaning up a bit
        text = text.Replace(".", ""); //Just cleaning up a bit
        text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
        string[] arr = text.Split(' '); //Create an array of words

        foreach (string word in arr) //let's loop over the words
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word)) //if it's in the dictionary
                dictionary[word] = dictionary[word] + 1; //Increment the count
            else
                dictionary[word] = 1; //put it in the dictionary with a count 1
        }
        return(dictionary);
    }
```

However my functions aren't seeing the dictionary that I created at the start and I do not know how to return a dictionary from a function. I have tried declaring my dictionary static and/or public and such but I just get more errors.

Comment: You should put the dictionary variable to out side the Form1() method, make it to global variable

Comment: @trungtin1710 That's not a global variable.

Comment: L-Three pointed it out right. you can't access it in your method, because it is out of scope. brackets (`{` and `}`) show you the scope. Out of this brackets the variable does not exist any longer. the garbage collector freed the memory.

Comment: You don't know what the Garbe Collector does. And when. But @JensHorstmann is right, it is out of your scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare your dictionary at class level:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

     public Form1()
     {
          InitializeComponent();        
     }
 }
```